# Angular2 Http request is prepending baseURL to POST request

Tags: angular

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue I'm encountering when making a POST request to a service endpoint.

For Example, when I make a POST Request like this:

```
getUpdaterComputers(requestParameters): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('/api/computer/updatercomputers', requestParameters).map(response => response.json());
    }
```

and run the project locally the Request URL in console window is something like this http://localhost:4569/api/computer/updatercomputers which is expected.

However when I make a post request to a different service endpoint like this:

```
return this.http.post(`${this.assetsUrl}/computer/update/multi`, request, {
            headers: new Headers({
                'x-apikey': this.appConfigService.getXApiKey()
            })
        }).map(response => response.json());
```

In console windows I see the Request URL to something like this: `http://localhost:4569/https://someotherAPI.com/computer/update/multi` which fails. When I console.log the This.assetUrl, I see that it doesn't have the localhost part in request URL.

Can someone please tell me where I need to look in order to have my post request drop the baseURl from the http.post request.

Comment: Does your assetsUrl start with a forward slash (/)? like ```/https://...```

Comment: Show your assetsUrl variable declaration and updates, please.

Comment: high chance you have interceptor that adds your base url

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help, so we have a version of this project pushed to production and it works as expected, nothing has changed other that a lot of the libraries used by this project were updated to their latest version. issue started happening after updating libraries. I tried looking to see if we have any interceptor but I couldn't find any.

Comment: so, for anyone that lands to this page with a similar issue, the issue was not even with Angular but with AspCore endpoint, it was returning the assetsUrl endpoint wrapped in double quotes. ex. ""https://assets.chargeitpro.com"". This was introduced when the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc was updated, the fixed was to add the Produces("text/plain") decorator to the endpoint.